# Problem using [].substring()

Tags: apex, class, wrapper-class

I am having some issues using [].substring(). I am limited by using it. I would like to use a different approach because the qty can vary on length and this is not working for this solution. I will appreciate any help!

here is the System.debug

```
 USER_DEBUG [241]|DEBUG|(relatedObjectRow:[obj=NRProducts__c:{Name=105826985,  Id=a0Cf00000014LzCEAU},  selected=true,  testfield=999])
```

here is the button code:

```
public void cloneSelectedObjects2(){

 SOStoupload = new List<Purchase_Order_Details__c>();
  List<String> lista= new  List<String>();

  for (relatedObjects relatedObject : objectChildren)
 {
for (relatedObjectRow row : relatedObject.objectRows) 
{
    if (row.selected)
    {

        lista.add(row.toString());

    } 
}
//here for loop to get values
for (String str : lista)
{
     String[] inputvalues = str.split(',');

  System.debug(inputvalues);

              //create new pODetails
                Purchase_Order_Details__c pod= new Purchase_Order_Details__c(
                Purchase_Order__c = objecttext,
                NRProducts__c =inputvalues[1].substring(4,22),
                Qty_NR__c = Decimal.valueof(inputvalues[3].substring(14,17)) //values from inputField (testField)

                );


                SOStoupload.add(pod);

  }
  }
 insert SOStoupload;  

}
```

wrapper class here

```
    public class relatedObjects
 {
  public List<relatedObjectRow> objectRows { get; set; }
public String pluralLabel      { get; set; }
public String relatedName{get;set;}
public String relatedId{get;set;}


public relatedObjects(List<relatedObjectRow> objectRows, 
                      String pluralLabel,
                      String relatedFieldName)

{
  this.objectRows = objectRows;
  this.pluralLabel = pluralLabel;
  this.relatedName = relatedName;
 this.relatedId = relatedId;

   }   
 }     


 public class relatedObjectRow
 {
public sObject obj      { get; set; }
public Boolean selected { get; set; }
public String testfield {get;set;}
public String relatedId{get;set;}

public relatedObjectRow(Sobject obj)
{
  this.obj      = obj;
  // All object rows are selected by default.
  this.selected     = true;
}

 public String getName ()
     {
  try{
    return '' + obj.get('Name');
  } catch (Exception e){
    return '';
  } 
  }

    public String getId ()
     {
  try{
    return '' + obj.get('Id');
  } catch (Exception e){
    return '';
  } 
  }

 }
```

here is the solution, someone help me with this([Get multiple values from VF Page and pass them to the class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33908/)):

```
  public void cloneSelectedObjects2(){

SOStoupload = new List<Purchase_Order_Details__c>();

for (relatedObjects relatedObject : objectChildren) {
    List<relatedObjectRow> selectedRelatedRows = new List<relatedObjectRow>();

    for (relatedObjectRow row : relatedObject.objectRows) {
        if (row.selected) {
            selectedRelatedRows.add(row);
        } 
    }

    //here for loop to get values
    for (relatedObjectRow row : selectedRelatedRows) {

        //create new pODetails
        Purchase_Order_Details__c pod = new Purchase_Order_Details__c();

        // not sure where this objecttext is coming from
        pod.Purchase_Order__c = objecttext;

        // use the sObject.get() to grab the ID field value from the inner object
        pod.NRProducts__c = row.obj.get('Id');

        // get the 'entered value' from the wrapper class and convert to decimal
        pod.Qty_NR__c = Decimal.valueOf(row.EnteredValue);


        SOStoupload.add(pod);

    }
}

insert SOStoupload;
```

}

Comment: Can you clarify on what you are trying to do? Don't really want to infer it by reading through your code

Comment: Hi EricSSH, when the row in a table is selected i need to get the values, I added a inputField in the table and I need to get that value as well. The code above is working but as you see I am using subString() and that won't work for this solution because the qty length will change. So I was wondering is there is another way to get values from the row. I will add the wrapper class in the question.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to change

```
List<String> lista= new  List<String>();
```

to be a list of lists 
like:

```
List<List<String>> lista= new  List<List<String>>();
```

Then when you are iterating through your `relatedObject.objectRows`, you could add each field on the object (obj, selected, testfield, relatedId) into the list as it's own string.

That way instead of splitting the string and using .substring to access the information you want, you can just index into the array for each field.

Comment: hello Kyle, thank you for your answer, could you please modify the scrip i am new in this and don't follow this part you could add each field on the object (obj, selected, testfield, relatedId) into the list as it's own string. thank you in advance

Comment: Actually, just realized I hadn't read your code closely enough. What are the values you are trying to extract with your substrings?

Comment: kyle, thank you for trying to help me. i updated the question with a solution. have a great day!